# can i take off the CPU cooler to clean it and put it back on without reapplying thermal paste

Tags: cpu, motherboard, cpu-cooler

My CPU cooler is too big so i cant get my motherboard out to clean it it's like 7 years old and I need to get the dust out. I have tried to take it out without taking off the motherboard but it doesn't fit.

Comment: Thermal paste is required.  Your CPU will overheat without adequate cooling.  Thermal paste is required to accomplish that

Comment: @SolarMike - You submitted a comment as an answer.  The community expects more than a single sentence when answering a question.  You should explain in detail, and backup your statements if possible, on the reason thermal paste is required.  **You were told to expand on your answer, and you choose to delete it, that is entirely on you.**

Comment: @SolarMike - You decided to delete it instead of improving it.  That is entirely your choice.  Quality content will be upvoted.  It does not matter when it was modified or submitted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**That is a bad idea! Continue reading...**

You need physical contact to move heat efficiently from the **CPU** heatspreader to the heatsink. The role of **thermal paste** is to "fill in the gaps" and allow for better transfer of heat from the heatspreader to the heatsink.

**What will happen if I don't put a thermal paste in my processor and heatsink?**

Things don't work as efficiently as they should. Your CPU's operating temperature will be higher. It may need to slow itself down (thermal throttling) to stop from overheating and failing.

Does this mean that your CPU will burn out and die? No. Does it mean that it is more likely to? Yes. Does it mean that your CPU will throttle? No. Does it mean that it is more likely to? Yes. Can you run your CPU without thermal paste for years and still have an operating computer? Yes. Is it a good idea to try? No.

The truth is that properly applied thermal paste is an important component of a cooling system and going without it is a *bad idea*. It's also a good idea to service your CPU every now and then (once every year or two) and replace dried and cracked thermal compound with a fresh application. If you find that thermal paste wasn't applied to your CPU when it was assembled, that's bad, but it isn't the end of the world. Modern CPUs will attempt to shut down before reaching a temperature at which damage occurs, and before that, they will slow themselves down.

Comment: I won't vote you down, but I do disagree with this post. You say that it can run... well, I've had instances where I seated the cooler on the CPU with thermal paste applied even, and due to improper contact, the system would not even turn on. I've also seen instances where the thermal compound was solidified and reseating the cooler because by accident it got loose (yes, someone applied too much pressure not thinking there was any paste between), and just reseating it was a no-go. We had to remove all thermal paste and reapply it. So the chances for it to work are really slim, if at all.

Comment: Some CPU's can run for a small amount of time without thermal paste or even without a cooler, though I think modern CPU's have a built-in mechanism against such thing.

Also yes you might be able to run the CPU without thermal paste depending on what CPU you have, and what you're exactly doing on your computer. If the CPU exceeds the firmware limit of the heat than it shuts down the whole system.

Comment: Had family members CPU build up with dust and stop the fan many years ago; their computer ran a snails pace for months but did not get damaged.  Bought a new fan, blew out the dust, and things went back to normal.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should replace the compound if you remove the heatsink.

Thermal paste is generally either a near-fluid or putty like compound when applied.  Over time it "sets" into a solid due to heat and forms an effective seal between the CPU case and heatsink.

When you remove the heatsink you break that seal and create gaps in the compound. As the compound is no longer malleable it cannot reflow into gaps when you refit the heatsink and can easily end up with air bubbles and poor contact between the CPU and heatsink.

Answer (score 0):

Why remove the heatsink?

Purchase an air duster (compressed air, or a blower designed for the same role) to blow the dust out of your case.  Less work involved, and no need to worry about damaging your system*

*don't blow the fans - preferably hold them in place while cleaning.  This prevents them from spinning up and acting as a turbine generating power.